# How to avoid tracking 'clicks' from url shorteners themselves?

Tags: url, twitter, google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Im using **google shorten url** to short my link , i used this link to post on twitter using my php application.

To track the source of that page link, iam doing visit count update on my php page when some clicked that link. when i passing my url to google shorten api it automatically ping my site so my visit count increasing, and twitter is too doing that same. Because of this i got 2 to 5 clicks count on db. Can anyone help me how to handle this issue? I would like track how many clicks done by user not from this both google shorten api and twitter shorten url api

Answer (score 1):

The easy / lazy way is to do further testing and see if a consistent number of hits come from Google and Twitter. If so, you just pre-adjust the count to subtract that number of hits for every shortened URL.

The more rigorous way is to [detect User-Agent headers](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm) for each page request. If it's from Google or Twitter, ignore it. If it's from anything else, increment your clicks count.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar kind of problem. When the hit is being made by google, then in the request header it sets `From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com`. We used this header information and implemented custom logic to exclude hits from google-bots.